# How to make more beautify code?

Tags: php

I have a lot of code in some classes, when I must pre-declare array `$keys = [];`:

```
public function convertIdStringToMongoID($array_id = array())
{

    $keys = [];

    foreach ($array_id as $k => $id) {

        $keys[] = new \MongoId($id);
    }

    return $keys;
}
```

It looks now good, how to make this more beauty?

Comment: Do not listen to anyone, your code is beautiful)

Comment: That should do it

Comment: You don't need `$k =>`; `foreach ($array_id as $id)` is enough (`$k` is not used in the posted code).

Comment: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: add an `array` parameter type hint either check it with `is_array()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) can try mapping your array, something like this:

```
public function convertIdStringToMongoID($array_id = array())
{
   $func = function($id) {
       return new \MongoId($id);
   };
   return array_map($func, $array_id);
}
```

Or according to [this example](https://coderwall.com/p/bgy0rq/use-php-array_map-in-classes), something like:

```
public function convertIdStringToMongoID($array_id = array())
{
   return array_map(array($this, 'to_id'), $array_id);
}

private function to_id($id) {
  return new \MongoId($id);
}
```

Both examples use functional programming approach.

Comment: Or even use some outer function for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is clean and fast. You can write it in a more compact way using [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

```
public function convertIdStringToMongoID(array $array_id = array())
{
    return array_map(function ($id) { return new \MongoId($id); }, $array_id);
}
```

Some people might consider it more beautiful, others will say it is slightly more difficult to read and understand it this way.
Both will agree that the execution time of this version is slightly longer than your version. However, the difference is not significant, there are other places to search for optimizations (access to disk and external resources, database queries, Mongo etc.)